# typescript and ts-node-dev. cannot find module ''src/app'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I'm using typescript in an express application, when i run it, i get this message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/app'
```

The application entry point is a file with path `src/server.ts` and the app with the express instance is at `src/app.ts`.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

A weird fact is that when i run my tests with jest, from some reason, it works fine. Here my jest.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', './'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/dist/'],
}
```

## Edit

here is my scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "tsnd src/server.ts",
    "generate": "plop ",
    "ga": "plop action",
    "debug": "tsnd --inspect=0.0.0.0:7001 --exit-child --respawn src/server.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.ts'"
  },
```

i'm running with `npm start`

Comment: are you importing `src/app` in `server.ts`? if so, it should just import `./app` because it is a relative file. Also, what command are you running to start the app (what does your `package.json` `scripts` look like)? You might have to run `ts-node src/app.ts`

Comment: I'm putting my package. scripts in the trhead. The problem with using relative path is that i have severals that uses the absolute path in my project and i have a code generator (with plop) that relys on the fact that we can access files from the root.